# Using the default PROPAGATION_REQUIRED with @Transactional behaviour

Tags: spring, transactions

I know that when you put say @Transactional on a class each method inside will be executed as part of one single transaction if you call them one after the other in sequence because the default spring transactional behaviour is PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. See docs http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation . So assume I have a class like:

```
 @Service
 @Transactional
 public class ActorServiceImpl implements ActorService
 {
    public void method1(){}

    public void method2(){}
 }
```

However, I want to know what happens if method1 throws an exception and the transaction has to be rolled back then I guess method2 will never be executed because the transaction has already committed due to the exception in method1?

Comment: If you call method1 and method2 in sequence you get 2 individual transactions not a single one.

Comment: I don't think so. See this picture http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: trust me it does... You will only get a single transaction if you call method1 and method2 in sequence from another transactional method.

Comment: Well, the docs say something else. See here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#PROPAGATION_REQUIRED .I will trust you if you prove it or at least provide some docs where it says something different

Comment: @george in the picture you linked to, a transactional method of a bean calls another transactional method of another bean bean. The second method is thus executed in the same transaction as the first one. This is very different from calling a transactional method, then calling a second transactional method. In that case, a transaction is started for the first method and is committed/rollbacked after it returns, then a second transaction is started for the second method and is committed/rollbacked after it returns.

Comment: oh. yeah, I got it. Oh well then in that case required is the same as required_new pretty much?

Comment: The docs don't state that the docs state as I said it works. And REQUIRED and REQUIRES_NEW are different. So no it isn't the same. If you REQUIRES_NEW is detected and there is an ongoing transaction, that is suspended and a new transaction is started.

Comment: you did not explain anything. "trust me it does" does not sound promising at all..